# Chebyshev's inequality for sum of indicator variables

Tags: probability, inequality

If $N = \sum_{i=0}^{n} I_i$ where $I_i$ is the indicator variable of event $A_i$, with $P(A_i)=p_i$, how can one show that

$$
P(N=0) \leq \frac{\operatorname{Var}(N)}{E(N)^2}
$$

using Chebyshev's inequality or otherwise?

I don't know how to apply Chebyshev's inequality here – it doesn't seem like there's anything that has the right form.

Edit:
The first part of the question is to calculate the expectation and variance of $N$ in terms of $p_i$ and $p_{ij} = P(A_i \cap A_i)$ - perhaps this could be useful for the second part?

---

Edit:
Full question:

[image]

Comment: How do you know $p_{ij}$ without independence of events $A_i$'s?  Chebyshev/Markov holds for all rv w/o looking into their characteristics, so in most cases, those bounds are no good.

Comment: We don't know what the $p_{ij}$ are, we just have to find the variance of N in terms of $p_i$ and $p_{ij}$.

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers. [Scanned pages from books are discouraged on SE network](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/155600/259305). Questions should contain sufficient context so that it is [answerable with the text alone](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807/290189).

Comment: The calculations for $var(N)$ and $E(N)$ are irrelevant.  Chebyshev is just Markov's inequality applied to "squared deviation from average" $(X-E[X])^2$.  Markov's inequality's proof is incredibly simple: get a whole $E[X]$, truncate it with $1_{\{X \ge a\}}$, write out the inequality and bounds, and wrap out things.  You may replace $E[X]$ with $var(X)$ and rework the proof.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have an answer to this question but would appreciate any feedback! :)

---

Firstly note that
$$
P(N=0) \leq P(|N-E(N)| = E(N)) 
$$

We know that

$$
P(|N-E(N)| \geq E(N)) \leq \frac{Var(N)}{E(N)^2}
$$
using Chebyshev.

We want to connect these two expressions. We can do this by noting that
$$
P(|N-E(N)| \geq E(N)) = P(|N-E(N)| = E(N)) + P(|N-E(N)| > E(N)) \geq P(|N-E(N)| = E(N))
$$

Therefore, putting this all together, we have

$$
P(N = 0) \leq P(|N-E(N)| = E(N)) \leq P(|N-E(N)| \geq E(N))\leq \frac{Var(N)}{E(N)^2}
$$

Comment: The first equality is wrong: what about the event $\{N = 2 E[N] = 2 \sum_i p_i \}$?

Comment: Good point thanks. I have edited it